# Error: arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step. x Could not create a temporary column for `..1`

Tags: r, sorting

I am getting this error when trying to sort output in descending order by "purpose"

`Error: arrange() failed at implicit mutate() step.  x Could not create a temporary column for ..1`.

input that leads to this error is :

```
> lcdf %>% group_by(purpose) %>% tally() %>% count(purpose) %>% arrange(desc(count_purpose))
```

The count of one of the variables is 1, which for some reason seems to be what is causing this error, if I am understanding it correctly. Not sure how to get past this.

Comment: If you applied `count` on `purpose`, the column name would be `purpose` and not `count_purpose`

Comment: Thanks, That eliminates the error, but doesn't solve the problem of needing the output to be sorted in descending order by count of purpose.

Comment: Because you are using `tally` before count which does the same thing.  Just use only `count` as in my solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default column of frequency from `count` is `n`.  So, it is the one that should be `arrange`d.  Also, we don't need `group_by`, `tally` and `count`

```
library(dplyr)
lcdf %>%
  count(purpose) %>% 
  arrange(desc(n))
```